# MSACCESS VBA: Add borders to Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

The below does not work. How do I add borders? Thanks!

```
            Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            objApp.Visible = True
            Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("aFile.xls", True, False)
            objApp.Cells.Select
            objApp.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            objApp.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With

            Set objApp = Nothing
```

Comment: What's your error message or is it just not working?  Why select the cells first?  You should be able to just use `objApp.cells` directly.

Comment: No error msg. objApp.Cells.Borders did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBA code did not work for me so I discovered a workaround. Since I was using an Excel template to create the Excel sheet. I modified the Excel template to print Gridlines.

To enable Gridlines to Print:

Excel > Print Preview > Page Setup > Sheet > Check mark gridlines under Print.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and the "borders.weight" construction works for me and there's no need to use ".cells" to refer to a range either. Example:

```
.Range("A11:H11").Borders.Weight = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("aFile.xls", True, False)
wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Borders.Weight=xlThin
```

Better to avoid formatting the entire sheet needlessly.

Comment: `wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:K").Borders.Weight = xlThin`  This did not work. Nothing happened.

Comment: Works for me (XL2007).  Is it the first sheet you're working with?

Comment: I must be doing something different. I tried `wb.Sheets(1).Activate wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:K").Borders.Weight = xlThick` Nothing happened. If I find the solution I'll post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objApp.Visible = True
Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("aFile.xls", True, False)
With objApp.Cells.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = 0
End With
```

This should give you a border around all cells on the ACTIVE sheet of the workbook you opened.  Diaganols are off by default.

Comment: How do I set sheets(1) as the active sheet? objApp.ActiveSheet = wb.Sheets(1)?

Comment: Your code seems to be placing borders around the Active Cell. How do I select the Active Sheet? Thanks.

Comment: wb.Sheets(1).Activate   will activate the first sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Access doesn't know the Excel enumerations, try this:

```
Function CreateBorders(Range As Object)
    With Range.Borders(7)
        .LineStyle = 1
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = 2
    End With
    With Range.Borders(8)
        .LineStyle = 1
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = 2
    End With
    With Range.Borders(9)
        .LineStyle = 1
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = 2
    End With
    With Range.Borders(10)
        .LineStyle = 1
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = 2
    End With
    With Range.Borders(11)
        .LineStyle = 1
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = 2
    End With
    With Range.Borders(12)
        .LineStyle = 1
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = 2
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this pretty long time, after reading this dicussion it gave me some ideas and I changed my codes accordingly and it works for me.. Here is the code to share with you..

To format all borders to xlMedium:

```
With objApp.Worksheets("AR Tab").Range(.cells(4, 5), .cells(4, 8))
  '.LineStyle = xlMedium    
  .Borders.Weight = 3
End With
```

To format only left border to xlMedium:

```
With objApp.Worksheets("AR Tab").Range(.cells(4, 5), .cells(4, 8))
  '.LineStyle = xlMedium
  .Borders("1").Weight = 3
End With
```

If you would like to have different linestyle:

```
.Borders("1").LineStyle = 1 'Line Style xlContinues
.Borders("1").LineStyle = 2 'Line Style xlDash
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Get the workbook and worksheet as variables, then just set the borders for used range.

```
Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(strXLSFile)
Set objXLSheet = objXLBook.Sheets("Name of Sheet")

objXLSheet.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer is a less complete version of previous answers to an eight year old question. Please consider formatting with inline code blocks and adding explanation / clarification that would highlight why this is a better answer than the previous set.